# Removing class ambiguity without being overly verbose

Tags: java, namespaces, import

I have a Java library that I am working on with a directory structure which looks like the following:

```
/com
  /example
    /LibX
      Server.java
      Client.java
```

Now, from a project which is using the above classes, it seems to me that importing `com.example.LibX.*` and using `Client client = new Client(...);` is a bit ambiguous, as "Client" could mean anything. Therefore, I tried the following, only to receive "package not found" errors:

```
import com.example.*;

LibX.Client client = new LibX.Client(...);
```

It is possible to do what I described? Or is there another way to remove the ambiguity without using `com.example.LibX.Client`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your concern about ambiguity is unnecessary - if you have an ambiguous reference your class won't compile - 
e.g.

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.sql.Date;

public class Test {

        private Date date;
}
```

won't compile. So if you can compile the class then by definition you don't have an ambiguous reference.

Incidentally LibX.Client is a bit confusing. Usually classnames are capitalized, package names lowercased, so if you did that (if LibX was a top-level package and you were giving the full name) it looks more like an inner class reference, as in Andy's response above.

Answer (score 3):

Java packages are not hierarchical, even if they may sometimes look like it.  You can't import a "tree" of packages, as you're suggesting.  You either need to import a specific package with a wildcard, or you import the specific class name, or you use fully-qualified class names in your code directly.

The following isn't ambiguous, and is considered best practice:

```
import com.example.LibX.Client;

...

Client client = new Client(...);
```

In a world where IDEs can organise your imports for you, there's no reason not to state them all explicitly.

Comment: And if I have another class: `com.example.LibZ.Client`, I would use the full name to access it instead of importing it?

Comment: Yes, it you have to use both Client classes in the same class.

Comment: @Tim: In practice, that's not very common. For example, `Client` isn't a good name for a type, it's almost always preferable to give it a more descriptive name.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible if you're willing to group Client and Server as static nested classes.

```
public class LibX {
  public static class Client {
    //...
  }

  public static class Server {
    //...
  }
}
```

Now you can `import mypak.LibX` and then do `new LibX.Client()`. This has the unfortunate drawbacks of forcing you to group your classes and also creating the additional empty LibX class.

Comment: Random fact: Inner- and nested classes are not considered safe as Java changes all private modifiers of the outer classes members to package scope.

Answer (score 0):

There's no such mechanism like what you described.  Your only other possibility is to use single class imports:

```
import com.example.LibX.Client;
```